# make text view touch the activity boundary

Tags: android

I want to fill entifre space around text view with color,,but due to less text it fill some and left some space around it.Link for image is below
problem 
http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/817/capturetxnw.png

and i want this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/171/capture1xw.png/

Comment: ur files asking passwords.. why don't u just upload files here only

Comment: can u post your layout.xml.., in which u are setting textviews??

Comment: @Ankit  here is the link to it:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/93226534/New%20Text%20Document%20(2).txt

Comment: Please edit question and place code here, I don't have access to file hosting site..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout.xml file, set the textview layout parameters like this:

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/myTextView"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The key part is the : android:layout_width="fill_parent". This will basically fill up the entire screen and effectively solve your problem. If you need any further clarifications do ask!

Answer (score 0):

make your scroll view width as `fill_parent`